# Run length encoding function (no libraries or object methods)

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, compression, run-length-encoding

I need to write a program that using run length encoding to compress a list. I have no idea how to do it and after changing my program a little bit at a time I don't even know what it is doing now.

We aren't allowed to import and libraries or use python string or list object methods (like `append()`).

This is pretty much where I am now:

```
def rle(x):
    c_list = []
    count = 0 
    for num in x: 
        if x[num] == x[num - 1]:
            c+=[x[num], count]
            count+= 1
     # ...
     return c
```

using this list as an example:

```
[8,8,8,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,9,8,1,1,1,1,3,3]
```

It'll return this:

```
[6, 0, 6, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 
5, 7, 5, 8, 5, 9, 6, 10, 6, 11, 8, 12, 8,
13, 8, 14, 8, 15]
```

Which is obviously way off.

Comment: What _should_ it return?

Comment: it should return a compressed list like: [8,3,4,1,5,3...]

Answer (score 1):

What is the encoding supposed to be? Assuming tuples of `(element, count)` then you could implement a generator:

```
def rle(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    e, c = next(it), 1       # StopIteration silently handled before Py3.7
    for n in it:
        if n == e:
            c += 1
            continue
        yield (e, c)         # "yield from (e, c)" if you need a flat list
        e, c = n, 1
    yield (e, c)

>>> list(rle('aaaaaddddffgghjjjjj'))
[('a', 5), ('d', 4), ('f', 2), ('g', 2), ('h', 1), ('j', 5)]
>>> list(rle([8,8,8,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,9,8,1,1,1,1,3,3]))
[(8, 3), (4, 1), (5, 3), (6, 4), (9, 1), (8, 1), (1, 4), (3, 2)]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with "except", "StopIteration" and "try" so I am having a hard time following the program

Comment: `try: except:` allows you to handle exceptions, `next(it)` can throw an exception `StopIteration` if you pass in an empty iterable. Currently you don't need the try block because a quirk of generators silently handle `StopIteration` exceptions prior to Py3.7. I will update the code to remove the try block - it was there purely for future proofing given we are only on Py3.5

Answer (score 0):

```
def rle(x):
    prev = x[0]
    count = 0
    for item in x:
        if item == prev:
            count += 1
        else:
            yield prev, count
            prev = item
            count = 1
    yield prev, count

x = [8,8,8,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,9,8,1,1,1,1,3,3] 
print list(rle(x))
```

prints

```
[(8, 3), (4, 1), (5, 3), (6, 4), (9, 1), (8, 1), (1, 4), (3, 2)]
```

If you need

```
[8, 3, 4, 1, 5, 3, 6, 4, 9, 1, 8, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2]
```

simply replace each `yield` with 2 `yields`

```
yield prev
yield count
```

Comment: what is `start` for, it doesn't seem to be used. And it may need to guard against an empty list.